# how make the default value?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

There is a button **table** and **list**. Click on **table** items are displayed in a table. If you click on **list** - items are displayed in a list.
Сondition (**list** or **table**) is remembered using cookies

But when the cookie is empty, the default active button **list**, and the product is displayed in the table.

I need to display the products table and, by default, set the active button **table**.

And I do not understand where is the value `active` for the button **list**

To make the button value **table** `active` by default using **js** and only for first press.

**erb**:

```
<ul class="ctf--b-view-nav">
  <li class="<%= 'active' if cookies['filter-product-views'] != 'buble' %>">
    <a class="ctf--b-view-nav-list" href="">item</a>
  </li>
  <li class="<%= 'active' if cookies['filter-product-views'] == 'buble' %>">
    <a class="ctf--b-view-nav-cols" href="">table</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- container with items -->
<div class="infinite-table">
  <ul class="ctf--b-product-list <%= 'ctf--b-product-list-buble' unless cookies['filter-product-views'] == 'buble' %>">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**js**:

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
    $('.ctf--b-view-nav a').click(function() {
    if (!($(this).parent().hasClass('active')))
    {
        $('.ctf--b-view-nav li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        if ($(this).hasClass('ctf--b-view-nav-cols'))
        {
          $.cookie('filter-product-views', 'buble');
          $('.ctf--b-product-list').addClass('ctf--b-product-list-buble');
        }
        else{
          $('.ctf--b-product-list').removeClass('ctf--b-product-list-buble');
          $.cookie('filter-product-views', 'non-buble');
        }
        return false;

    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
  });
});
```

**css**: (for buttons use a sprite)

```
.ctf--b-view-nav { list-style:none; vertical-align:top; right:0; top:-50px; position:absolute; }
.ctf--b-view-nav li { float: left; padding:0 0 0 10px; }
.ctf--b-view-nav a { width:18px; height:18px; font-size:2em; line-height:0; display:block; }
.ctf--b-view-nav .active .ctf--b-view-nav-list { background-position:0 bottom; }
.ctf--b-view-nav .ctf--b-view-nav-cols { background-position:right 0; }
.ctf--b-view-nav .active .ctf--b-view-nav-cols { background-position:right bottom; }
```

Comment: You can use the `.fetch` method to get a key from the cookies and provide a default at the same time `cookies.fetch('filter-product-views', 'foo')`. But as written this question is very confusing and lacks a clear explaination of the desired outcome.

Comment: thanks. I'll try to explain better.

Comment: When I opened the browser for the first time - by default selected button "list", but goods are displayed in a table. (but this code works, but you have to do an extra click). I want to understand why the button is selected "list" by default. And then make a button for the "table" by default